# HMM probability and log probability always Infinity!

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling

I have a list of time series data, which I want to classified them with HMM.

for this I’m using **Jahmm**.
the data are binary vectors and they ate transformed to Observation vectors for more simplicity. Now, I want to do a binary classification.

> As an example:
>
> obs1 = [1,0,0,0,1,0,1]
>
> obs2 = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
>
> obs3 = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1]
>
> obs4 = [0,1,1,0,1,0,1]

first I have created K-means learner and optimize the learning process with Baum welch (as its said in jahmm), then when I want to calculate the Hmm probability which the trained observation, its always Infinity,
I have also tried with log and scaling methods and the LSE. none of them change the Infinity.

**here is my code**

> ```
>     OpdfMultiGaussianFactory opdfMGF = new OpdfMultiGaussianFactory(hcodeDim);
>     KMeansLearner<ObservationVector> kml = new KMeansLearner<ObservationVector>(hSNr, opdfMGF, trainData);
>     RegularHmmBase<ObservationVector> trainHmm = kml.iterate();     
>     System.out.println("Result TrainHmm " + trainHmm);
>     /* Baum-Welch learning */
>     RegularBaumWelchScaledLearnerBase bwl = new RegularBaumWelchScaledLearnerBase();
>     bwl.setNbIterations(100);
>     Hmm learntHmmTrain = bwl.learn(trainHmm, trainData);
>     System.out.println("Resulting HMM:\n" + learntHmmTrain);
>     System.out.println("probability at learnt hmm " +learntHmmTrain.probability(trainData.firstElement()));
> ```

```
    // This object measures the distance between two HMMs
    KullbackLeiblerDistanceCalculator klc = new KullbackLeiblerDistanceCalculator();

    // Incrementally improve the solution
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Distance at iteration " + i + ": "
                + klc.distance(learntHmmTrain,trainHmm));
        learntHmmTrain = bwl.iterate(learntHmmTrain, trainData);
    }
```

I have to mention that the klc.distance in always NaN.
does anybody have experience with this problem in jahmm? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution and wanted to post it here, maybe its usefull for others.
as its seen above my observation vector is always 1 or zero.that make the probabilities too small.Another problem was the lenght of the Observation sequences it was too long.
so I just change the 1 to 100, and cut the Observation sequences at a point.
now is every thing fine.